# What's this code doing, and how can I manipulate it?

Tags: c++

OK. It's been a long time since I've worked with C++, and I think I've got a general idea of what this code is doing. (I am taking the relevant bits of the code, assume proper libraries are pulled in, and what not.)

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("text.txt");
int value;

while (inFile >> value)
{
    while (value > 0)
    {
        cout << value;
    }
}

inFile.close();
```

So, the first while function is basically searching the input file for ints, and the second one...prints it out? Or is it that if a file's input stream can't be put to an int, it leaves the value at 0? This really compact, uncommented code is...interesting.

Anyway. If I have how the above code works, I can probably figure this out on my own, but I'm here, so may as well. If I wanted to have it only print the first (variable) number of integers in a file, what would I need to do?

Comment: Is this code you found? `while (value > 0)` will be an infinite loop for the first above zero value.

Comment: It is not searching for `int`s, it reads `int`s into `value` in a loop.

Comment: Yes. I found the code. Apparently from a bad source. I'm not positive why I'm getting downvoted for it, but OK.

Comment: Downvotes are probably from folk who think you could have turned the snippet into a small program and stepped through the program with a debugger to watch what happens more easily than you asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, unless your compiler can't find the file to be read, despite various methods, and so you have no means of debugging it, save for asking if anyone knows what it's doing...

Comment: Sidenote: The compiler's not going to look for the file to be read. That'll be done by the program at runtime.  Since the path is not an [absolute path,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)  where the program goes looking for the file may not be where you think it will look. You'll have to keep an eye on the [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I wanted to have it only print the first (variable) number of
>   integers in a file, what would I need to do?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile{ "text.txt" };
    int value;
    int num_values;

    std::cin >> num_values;

    for(int i{}; i < num_values && (inFile >> value); ++i)
        cout << value;
}
```

Comment: A better example would obtain `num_values` at runtime (ie, from user input) and not hard-code it. Also, the loop condition `&& inFile` could be replaced with `inFile >> value` so it can be removed from the loop body. `cin >> num_values; for(int i = 0; (i < num_values) && (inFile >> value); ++i) { cout << value; }`

Comment: So, what's the 'inFile >> value' doing? Does it work only in continuous strings of (spaced) integers? Can it handle negatives?

Comment: @SangoDragon it extracts values of type `int` from the \*stream\* `inFile` seperated by `isspace()` characters. it handles the whole range of possible `int`s.

Comment: @SangoDragon `>>` will read into whatever variable you ask it to (or fail to compile if no one's provided a `>>` overload to read into that type of variable). In this case you have the right of that it will read a sequence of space-delimited values into an `int`. Any thing that can be translated into an `int` will be read, and this means positive and negative integers are game. If you supplied 123.456, 123 would be read and printed, bu the . would fail to parse and end the loop. The error flag would have to be `clear`ed and the offending input handled elsewhere.